# I need to be able to read and write my csv file from github or dropbox

Tags: ruby, csv, heroku, sinatra

I am making a webpage for a company and I have it hosted on heroku, when I upload a file link to my csv on my local computer it works, but when using the deployed version it only works for a while as it stores the info in a temp file.It does not write to my csv on GitHub. M question is how to write to my GitHub using ruby and Sinatra . here is snippet of some of my code. any help would be great as this is due like now

```
get '/update_csv' do
csv = CSV.read("citywholesale.csv")

erb :update_csv, :locals =>{:csv => csv}
end

get '/upload' do
erb :upload, :locals =>{:message => "Please Enter all the required information."}
end

def newfilename(filename)
if filename.include?("dl=0") && filename.include?("dropbox")
filename.chomp!("dl=0")
filename << "raw=1"
end
filename
end

post '/upload' do

filename = params[:filename]
caption = params[:caption]
validity = params[:validity]
signtype = params[:signtype]
featured = params[:featured]

citywholesale = "citywholesale.csv"
citywholesale = File.open(citywholesale,'a')

 newfilename = newfilename(filename)
 citywholesale.write( newfilename + "," + caption + "," + validity + "," +        signtype + "," + featured + "\r")
 citywholesale.close
 redirect '/update_csv'
 end

post '/edit_upload' do
csv = CSV.read("citywholesale.csv")
csv_row = params[:edit].to_i
row = csv[csv_row]

erb :edit_upload, :locals =>{:id => csv_row, :image => row[0], 
                  :caption => row[1], :active => row[2], :signtype => row[3], :featured => row[4]}
```

end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean you have a repo on GitHub with a file you have to update? Let me first say that this is a bad idea, as GitHub is made to host version controlled code. A much better solution is to just store this CSV on that server or on something like [Amazon's S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

If, however, you are convinced that GitHub is the right way to go, the only way I would think you could do this is to use GitHub's Gists and use their API to do it. Here's the documentation:

https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#edit-a-gist

Comment: agree  and even with the gist idea ,  it is still a misuse :C

Comment: @Jamie Rodas I can use anything I need to to upload to. I checked out their documentation but am having hard time making head or tails of it, infact i was just now looking at the s3 but that to is kinda like wow. Im still pretty new to this whole thing so any help would be cool

Comment: GitHub is made to store code repos, not data. Data should be stored on the server, a database, or a service expressly designed to store it (S3). Going by what you wrote, I'm guessing your best bet is to just make the file you save not a temporary one. Then, if you need to use the data locally, you can  `scp` from the server and get a local copy.